# the table at the end of Theoretical Computer Science Cheat Sheet

Tags: matrices, pattern-recognition, combinatorial-designs

[Theoretical Computer Science Cheat Sheet](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf), created by [Steve Seiden](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/242581.242585), is a hodgepodge of well-known mathematical theorems and notions.

I can understand (or guess at least) many of them, but I'm not sure about this 10-by-10 table at the end of the document. What is this matrix? The document has no explanation at all, and I'm wondering why the author put in a *cheat sheet*.

Is there any special meaning in computer science or math that this matrix stands for?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's a $10\times 10$ magic square. You may be interested enough to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arranging the integers from $0$ to $99$ in a $10\times10$ square in such a way that no two in the same row or column have the same first digit or the same second digit.

It can be seen as a pair of orthogonal latin squares of order $10$: the first
digits form one square, the second digits the other.

Source: quick google search for the first row. [See this PDF, 23.5.1](http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.co.uk/pdf/bt/biggs/ch23_studentsolutions.pdf).